# Password matching message in primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I copied the exact code from this Primefaces http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1512 blog about easy password validation

```
<h:outputLabel for="pwd1" value="Password 1: *" />
                    <p:password id="pwd1" value="#{registerMB.password}"
                        feedback="false" match="pwd2" label="Password 1" required="true" />

                    <h:outputLabel for="pwd2" value="Password 2: *" />
                    <p:password id="pwd2" value="#{registerMB.password}"
                        feedback="false" label="Password 2" required="true" />

                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <p:commandButton value="Register" action="/pages/public/login" />
                        <p:commandButton value="Cancel" immediate="true"
                            action="/pages/public/login" />
                    </f:facet>
```

Validation works but I am only able to get the Validation Error.  The message Password 1 should match Password 2 is never displayed.  Is there anymore configuration for this?

I have Primefaces 3.4.1 downloaded

Comment: I can't see the message _Password 1 should match Password 2_.

Comment: Kindly look at the blog in the link

Comment: The simple fact is not all examples work exactly as advertised. Try setting the `message` attribute yourself and see if that doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `<p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"/>`

just like int [Primefaecs Password Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/password.xhtml)

```
<h:form id="form">  
<p:panel header="Match Mode">  
    <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"/>  

    <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="matchGrid">                     
        <h:outputLabel for="pwd1" value="Password 1: *" />  
        <p:password id="pwd1" value="#{passwordBean.password5}" match="pwd2" label="Password 1" required="true"/>  

        <h:outputLabel for="pwd2" value="Password 2: *" />  
        <p:password id="pwd2" value="#{passwordBean.password5}" label="Password 2" required="true"/>  
    </h:panelGrid>  

    <p:commandButton id="saveButton" update="matchGrid" value="Save" />  
</p:panel>  
</h:form>
```

Comment: Oops sorry..Probably some error during the cut and paste..but I have those already in the code.. Can you try to confirm this? Try the 3.4.1 release from primefaces..

Comment: paste your complete code... also , do you see any messages in your server console ?

Comment: @MarkEstrada if you have those elements in your code, please correct the original post.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add the following

1. validatorMessage atribute inside p:password tag id="pwd2":

   ```
               <p:password id="pwd2" value="#{registerMB.password}"
                   feedback="false" label="Password 2" required="true"     
                  validatorMessage="password 1 should match password 2"/>
   ```
2. add p:message tag to show the error below the h:form tag

   ```
    <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"/>
   ```